# How websites identify my web browser doesn't have the plugin installed?

Tags: python, plugins, browser

I am trying to scrape things out of a website. Whenever i access the website using curl or  python-requests, it keeps showing me that,i need to install a plugin to continue. But when i use a web browser which has the plugin installed , everything works fine.

I want to understand, how a website identifies that a web browser has the plugin installed or not?

Comment: Waht plugin are we talking about? Flash?

Comment: Does the website contain also the regular content? Or all you get from the `curl` or `python-requests` is a site with `Plugin required` message? Usually such checks are done via JS.

Comment: @kroolik Yes it has regular content. Not every page returns a 'plugin required message'. Only the page with video content on it.

Comment: @svineet It is looking for some kind of Divx plugin

Comment: Have you considered changing the User-Agent property of your requests script?

Comment: I updated the user agent recently, {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0'}

Comment: If you are able of detecting whether it is utilising JS to do the check (look for a block of code that shows/hides the message) you could use [python-spidermonkey](https://github.com/davisp/python-spidermonkey), or use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) with a profile that has those plugins installed (you can run selenium headless using [Xvfb](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xvfb)).

Comment: What happens in the browser if you disable the plugin?

Comment: I think the problem is with my code. It used to work for normal requests. Something changed on the server side. I tried using http sessions object requests.session. Things started working again! I don't see the plugin related error.